# Why Taasuaa (تاسوعا) is important for Shia?

Tags: shiism, muharram

There are two days that are so significant for Shiite as **"Taasuaa/تاسوعا And عاشورا/Ashura"** ... Actually usually they use and name these two days successive. (I am aware that Imam Hussein martyred at the tenth day of Moharam as Ashura), but I wonder what the importance of Taasuaa or تاسوعا is?

---

**References:**

[www.ahmadinejad.ir](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104014742/http://ahmadinejad.ir/%DA%86%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%AB%D9%87-%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D9%85%D9%87%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%9F/)

[www.pasokhgoo.ir](https://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/41370)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regard to the importance of Taasuaa (تاسوعا) as the ninth day of Moharam, it is quoted that Imam Jafar-a-Sadiq (peace be upon him) said:

> عن الصادق (عليه السلام) قال: تاسوعاء يوم حوصر فيه الحسين (عليه السلام)
>   وأصحابه بكربَلاءِ واجتمع عليه خيل أهل الشام وأناخوا عليه، وفرح ابن
>   مرجانة وعمر بن سعد بتوافر الخيل وكثرتها واستضعفوا فيه الحسين (عليه
>   السلام) وأصحابه وأيقنوا انه لايأتي الحسين (عليه السلام) ناصر ولايمدّه
>   أهل العراق، ثم قال بابي المستضعف الغريب.
>   2. بحار الأنوار الجامعة لدرر أخبار الأئمة الأطهار،علامه مجلسي، اسلاميه‏، تهران‏ ،ج‏45، ص 95.
>
> Taasuaa is the day that Hussain and his followers were surrounded and
>   the army of Shaam came against him. Ibn-Ziyad and Umar ibn-Sa'd were
>   happy of the added army. On that day they belittled Hussain(PBUH) and
>   his followers and they were ascertained that no other companion would
>   and not even the Iraqis will come to his support. May I be sacrificed
>   for my weak and alone father. Bihar al-anwar. Vol.45. Pg95.

It's basically the day that Imam Hussain and his followers got to know they were finished!
:(

Comment: Oh, what a sorrowful matter as what you have explained by that issue. Then Shia would be deserved to take the name Taasuaa with Ashuraa as two sorrowful days. despite a short answer, but you presented a great answer.